Churn Modeling- bad prediction in real world data
I have been working on a project for the last 6 months for work. It’s a model that predicts customer churn for our company, let say it’s a company that provides a monthly service for a fee similar to cable.
The input data set has about 1.5million customers for training/test. It consist mainly of 16 columns

monthly bill
financing used (1=y/0=n)
3-4) avg usage stats
total devices rented
total service visits to fix/replace equipment
total visits to add additional equipment
total any visits (8+9)
10-16) has X type of equipment (1=y/0=N)

I used pycarat to find the best model for both AUC and F1.
AUC: Catboost
F1: Xgboost
Now the data is imbalanced with there being more active customers than canceled. So I have the following code to account for that.
After train test split and the training the model I end up with model accuracies for both approaches in the low-mid 90’s on the training data. On the test data it’s right at 90. However as soon as I plug in this current month’s data into the model ( which it’s not seen) it only predicts 25% of the cancelled customers correctly. The rest don’t even have a probability of churn near coin flip, they are almost all near zero <.1.
The fact that the test data accuracy is so high made me suspicious right of the line. I don’t see anything in my input data that would suggest data leakage. Any suggestions would be helpful. Maybe im missing something, im pretty new to data science.
  X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size=0.2, random_state=42)

# Calculate class weights
total_samples = len(y_train)
class_counts = y_train.value_counts()
class_weights = {0: total_samples / (2 * class_counts[0]),  # Weight for class 0 (non churn)
                 1: total_samples / (2 * class_counts[1])}  # Weight for class 1 (churn)

catboost_model = CatBoostClassifier(class_weights=class_weights)
     


You might have more luck on the Cross Validated Stack Exchange than Stack Overflow, as I'm not sure this is really a code problem. However, just to check: (1) did you find you got really poor performance before trying to correct for class imbalance? (2) is there any seasonality in your monthly churn statistics?
